# how to make items load on drop down based on the radio button

Tags: asp.net

i have  req  in  my Application.  where  i have  3  radio  button    with option
 like
option 1 :5, 
option 2: 10,
option 3:   15,
    by  default  value  option 1    would  be  selected ,

if user  clicks  on  option 2  then the  items in  the    dropdown    should  show  10 values in dropworn, if it has  more than  10 items     we  can     give     div  tag inside  it   so that  all th  items ,

if user  clicks  on  option 3  then the  items in  the    dropdown    should  show  15 values in dropworn, if it has  more than  15 items .we  can  plcae th  items  with     div  tag

Answer (score 1):

I don't follow all the logic here, but to answer your question do the following:

1. Make sure that AutoPostback property is set to TRUE on your radiobuttons
2. Handle [CheckedChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged.aspx) event of the radiobutton, and fill the dropdown there